# WSO2 APIM adding sequence for backend server of API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am working on one scenario where I have add a sequence in the API using restAPI of APIM2.6.0 [https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#MediationPolicyCollection#apisApiIdPoliciesMediationPost]

Once the mediation policy is added to the respective API, do we have to publish the API once again. As when I am doing it from publisher once the sequence is added to direction IN, then I am saving it to get it reflected to synapse.

So, I believe if I am adding the same from restAPI, then also I have to republish it again to get it reflected to synapse.

Please let me know if the understanding is correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Normally, the once the API is published, all the changes will be auto deployed.

So, adding the mediation policies should also reflect without re-publishing the API.

**Update**

The answer above is for when using the UI. In REST API, we should republish the API.

Comment: no this is not happening in APIM2.6.0. It seems we need to update the sequence name in the api payload and use update rest API to make it updated. I am checking into it.

Comment: Ah... My mistake... In REST API we should republish. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to republish the API again to reflect the changes applied. You can check the code when adding a mediation policy for the API in [1].

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/85d02e1864bf77bd53bd269445995ab8e8e9641f/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/publisher/impl/ApisApiServiceImpl.java#L796